# How does the view that theta-roles are features work exactly? For example, in Hornstein 1999 Movement and Control

Tags: syntax, minimalism, theta-role

Hornstein 1999 says that theta-roles are features on verbs and a DP receives a theta-role by checking a theta-feature of a VP that it merges with. How would this be represented in a syntactic tree?

Here is a very simple example in which a DP gets an agent theta role from the little v head. Which tree would it be?

The one where agreement is downward like this?

[image: Downward agreement]

Or the one where agreement is upward like this?

[image: Upward agreement]

I think Boskovic and Takahashi (1998) "Scrambling and Last Resort" explains this well but I can't get the paper online. :/ I'd really appreciate it if someone had a PDF of it and could send it to me.

Comment: The latter tree is the correct one. The uninterpretable D feature (uD) projects to the intermediate projection v' where it Merges with the DP.